# 16-bit CRC-CCITT in Matlab

Tags: matlab, crc16

Given the `calcCRC()` C function shown below, what is the equivalent Matlab function?

**16-bit CRC-CCITT in C:**

```
/*
 * FUNCTION: calcCRC calculates a 2-byte CRC on serial data using
 * CRC-CCITT 16-bit standard maintained by the ITU
 * ARGUMENTS: queue_ptr is pointer to queue holding are a to be CRCed
 * queue_size is offset into buffer where to stop CRC calculation
 * RETURNS: 2-byte CRC
 */
unsigned short calcCRC(QUEUE_TYPE *queue_ptr, unsigned int queue_size) {
    unsigned int i=0, j=0;
    unsigned short crc=0x1D0F; //non-augmented initial value equivalent to augmented initial value 0xFFFF

    for (i=0; i<queue_size; i+=1) {
        crc ^= peekByte(queue_ptr, i) << 8;

        for(j=0;j<8;j+=1) {
            if(crc & 0x8000) crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021;
            else crc = crc << 1;
        }
    }

    return crc;
}
```

Below is the Matlab code I have come up with that seems to be equivalent but does not output the same results:

**(Incorrect) 16-bit CRC-CCITT in Matlab:**

```
function crc_val = crc_ccitt_matlab (message)
    crc = uint16(hex2dec('1D0F'));

    for i = 1:length(message)
        crc = bitxor(crc,bitshift(message(i),8));

        for j = 1:8
            if (bitand(crc, hex2dec('8000')) > 0)
                crc = bitxor(bitshift(crc, 1), hex2dec('1021'));
            else
                crc = bitshift(crc, 1);
            end
        end
    end

    crc_val = crc;
end
```

Here is a sample byte array, represented as an integer array:

```
78 48 32 0 251 0 215 166 201 0 1 255 252 0 1 2 166 255 118 255 19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0
```

The expected output is two bytes `base10(44 219)` which is `base2(00101100 11011011)` or `base10(11483)`.

My Matlab function gives `base10(85)` which is `base2(00000000 01010101)`.

Any ideas on what is causing the output to not be the expected?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through them both one line at a time and comparing the output of each line to see where they start to deviate?

Answer (score 1):

You should try `bitsll()` instead of `bitshift()`.  The former is guaranteed to do what you want, whereas the behavior of the latter depends on properties of `crc`.

You will also need to and with `0xffff` at the end.

Comment: Useful warning about [`bitshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html), which will pull in 1s when the input is negative. +1